# dotnet publish in Visual Studio 2022 adds CodeCoverage folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild

I have a .NET 7 application which contains one Unit Test project also in the solution. When I'm trying to publish the project, the output folder adds "CodeCovergae" folder which I don't want and how do I exclude it? I tried using  but no luck.

Release Output:
[image]

Test Project Structure:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Service Project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <startupobject>CService.Program</startupobject>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.5.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.6.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="7.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Text.RegularExpressions" Version="4.3.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\C.Business.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\C.Common.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\C.Middlewares.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\C.Repository.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="log4netDev.config">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
        <Content Update="log4netProd.config">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="CodeCoverage\**" />
        <Content Remove="CodeCoverage" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `CodeCoverage` Folder is created because you are referencing `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` in your Service project.

This package should only be targeted by test projects, you can remove it and then you will be fine.